# How can I add/create a user in firebase with the number and password (createUserWithPhoneAndPassword)? Anyone?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

How can I create/add a user in firebase with a number and password? Using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` worked but I need to use the number and password.
[image]
Using `createUserWithPhoneAndPassword` it doesn't work.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import '../Booking/booking.css'
import firebase from '../firebase'
// require('firebase/auth')

const Booking = () => {
    const initialFieldValues= {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        phone:'',
        password:''
      }
      var [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues);
    
      const handleInputChange = e => {
        var {name, value} = e.target
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name] : value
        })
      }

      const sendOTP=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();

        firebase.auth().createUserWithPhoneAndPassword(values.phone, values.password).then((u)=>{
            console.log(u)
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
}
    



    return (
        <div className="booking-container">
            <h1>Choose your destination and grap your taxi.</h1>
            <div className=" booking-images">
                <img src="assets/images/online-booking_1.jpg" alt="Order online" width="100%" height="100%" />
                <img src="assets/images/online-booking_2.jpg" alt="taxi Stop" width="100%" height="100%" />
            </div>
            <div className="booknow">
                <h1>BOOK TAXI NOW</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="center taxi-img">
                <img src="assets/images/booking-taxi.png" alt="taxi-Booking" />
            </div>
            <div className="booking-form">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div className=" form-book">
                        <div >
                            <p>First Name</p>
                            <input type="text" name="name" 
                            id="name" 
                            placeholder="Your Name" 
                            value={values.name}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <p>Email Address</p>
                            <input type="email" 
                            name="email" 
                            id="email" 
                            placeholder="abc@gmail.com" 
                            value={values.email}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <p>Phone</p>
                            <input type="number"
                            min="10" 
                            name="phone" 
                            id="phone"
                            value={values.phone} 
                            placeholder="+977-9812345678" 
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <p>Password</p>
                            <input type="password"
                            
                            name="password" 
                            id="password"
                            value={values.password} 
                            placeholder="******" 
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div className="center">
                    <div id="recaptcha"></div>
                        <button className="pt-10 btn-booknow" onClick={sendOTP}>BOOKNOW</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Booking
```

Comment: *it doesn't work.* is pretty vague - can you provide information about any errors you see as well as what steps you've gone through attempting to troubleshoot? Did you step through the code to ensure the vars are correct? For example, values could be empty which would cause it not to work.

Comment: When you turn on Phone Authentication in the console Sign In Method settings, there are additional steps you need to take within your app to enable that feature - the console shows the message *Phone Authentication requires additional configuration steps. Follow the steps for your platform.* to which you can click on the link and follow the presented steps. Did you do that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have change the number to email authentication